# How to make a custom add method for classes in C#

Tags: c#, function, addition

In python, if you have a class foo, you can make a custom add function for it like so:

```
class foo:
    def __add__(self, other):
        return stuff
```

and this lets you do things such as:

```
a = foo()
b = foo()
c = a + b
```

What is the equivalent in C#?

Comment: I think you're looking for operator overloading https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Look into operator overloading

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can implement an `operator`, for sample:

```
public class Foo
{
   public static Foo operator +(Foo f1, Foo f2) 
   {
      var foo = // some logic to generate a result
      return foo;
   }
}
```

and then you can try to use this operator:

```
var a = new Foo() { /* properties initialization */ };
var b = new Foo() { /* properties initialization */ };

var c = a + b;
```

You can implement more operators like `-`, `*`, `\`, `|`, `&`, just like the sample above.

See more in 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3):

This feature is called Operator overloading.

You can read about it here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Short example :

```
class Foo
{
    private int v;

    public Foo(int val)
    {
        v = val;
    }

    public static Foo operator +(Foo x1, Foo x2)
    {
        return new Foo(x1.v+ x2.v);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo d1 =  new Foo (10);
    Foo d2 = new Foo(11);
    d2 += d1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called "Operator Overloading". Please take a look at this tutorial:

[Operator Overloading Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx)

This teaches you how to use correct syntax to write a specific functionality of + operator for objects of class foo.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload operator +

```
public static MyClass operator +(MyClass m1, MyClass m2) 
{
    // logic goes here
}
```